# Guardar resultado de una función en una variable

Tags: php, mvc

Tengo esta función que lo que hace es generar el total para cada venta producida.

```php
public function getTotal() {
  $products = BuyProductData::getAllByBuyId($this->id);
  $total=0;
  
  foreach ($products as $px) {
    $p = ProductData::getById($px->product_id);
    $total += $p->price*$px->q;
  }
  
  return $total;
}
```

Pero no encuentro la manera correcta de pasar el resultado de esta función **getTotal** a una variable para utilizarlo para hacer un **PDF** y buscador de mi formulario ventas.

Para eso necesito almacenar el resultado de esta función en una variable *equis (x)* para luego utilizarlo.

El resultado de esta función si me muestra en pantalla cuando lo llamo con su nombre **getTotal**, pero al llamarlo en mi **FPDF** y buscador solo no me muestra nada. Por eso, deseo guardar el resultado de la función en una variable.

Comment: Hola Luz. ¿Ya probaste a hacer algo cómo `$var = getTotal();`?

Comment: Hola @Luz, tienes la función **getTotal()** en una clase, ¿cierto?

Comment: Si asi es, esta en una clase

Answer (score 0):

Si partimos del siguiente fragmento existente:

```php
public function getTotal() {
  $products = BuyProductData::getAllByBuyId($this->id);   
  $total=0;

  foreach ($products as $px) {
      $p = ProductData::getById($px->product_id);
      $total+=$p->price*$px->q;           
  }

  return $total;
}
```

En la que el método `getTotal()` se encuentra en una clase:

```php
class BuyData {
  ...
  
  public function getTotal() {
    ...

    return $total;
  }
}
```

Solo tendríamos que instanciar la clase donde se encuentra contenida la función:

```php
$buy = new BuyData();
```

Y luego ejecutar dicha función para almacenar su valor devuelto en una variable:

```php
$variable = $buy->getTotal();
```

Ten en cuenta que cuando una función tiene una palabra reservada `return` se le está indicando que devuelva un valor, es decir:

```php
...
public function getTotal() {
  ...
  return $total;
}
```

Donde `$total` será el valor devuelto por la función.

Comment: No necesito llamar a la clase madre con un require? en mi instancia.

Comment: La clase donde esta la funcion getTotal se llama BuyData y acabo de crear la instancia que nombre Instancia

Comment: La instancia la hice de esta forma: <?php

require ('BuyData.php');
$buy = new BuyData();
$variable = $buy->getTotal();

?>

Comment: Si la clase se encuentra en otro archivo, efectivamente, sí. Voy a actualizar la respuesta en función de los datos que me has suministrado en los comentarios.

Comment: Ya cambié el nombre de la clase para dar un poco más de contexto.

Comment: Y como llamo esa variable lo llame asi  $variable = InstanciaData::getTotal();  y me dice que InstanciaData no esta definida

Comment: Cuando digo instanciar me refiero a esto: `$buy = new BuyData()` para luego poder utilizar el método `getTotal()`. Es decir `$variable = $bui->getTotal()`

Comment: Trate de llamar el archivo InstanciaData a mi formulario con un require pero me dice Error fatal: require(): No se pudo abrir 'InstanciaData.php' (include_path'C:'xampp'php'PEAR')

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119188/discussion-between-david-e-luna-m-and-luz-martinez).